# How to filter listview that only contains username saved in sharedpref from firebase

Tags: android, listview, firebase

How can I sort all of the items from my firebase database to my listview? I want all the items that have just the username of the user that is saved on the shared preference. here is my code How i get items from firebase

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMessages);

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_of_rooms);


listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        while(i.hasNext()){
            set.add(((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getKey());
        }
        list_of_rooms.clear();
        list_of_rooms.addAll(set);

        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a local copy of your data list. Just sort it locally. E.g.

```
 root.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            while(i.hasNext()){
                set.add(((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getKey());
            }
            list_of_rooms.clear();
            list_of_rooms.addAll(set);
Collections.sort(list_of_rooms, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String s1, String s2)
        {
            return  s1.compareTo(s2);
        }
    });
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Updated question sir. Not to sort values but filter. Sorry for my mistake. Hehe

Comment: Could you show a example of your database design and how the username is stored?

Answer (score 0):

```
            while(i.hasNext()){
                set.add(((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getKey());
            }
            list_of_rooms.clear();
            list_of_rooms.addAll(set);

            arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(pref.getString("username", "").toString());

            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```